# What specifications of RAM module should I use for this PC?

Tags: memory, ramdisk

I want to upgrade my PC RAM module from 4GB to 8GB and I am a bit confused of the speed the 8GB module should be.

The instructions on the [manual](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=6431932&docLocale=en_US&docId=emr_na-c04341736) I downloaded says this:[image: instructions of the on manual I downloaded]

Except I am misunderstanding something, the current 4GB module concurs:

[image: present 4GB module]

[image: present 4GB module]

But the specifications of the PC says something different:

[image: PC specifications]

**What I know:**
The 8GB RAM I want to buy should be: PC3L, 12800.

**What I don't know**
The speed. Please is it 1600-MHz or 1333MHz?

### EDIT

More of the PC info:

[image: more pc info]

Comment: It's 1333Mhz it's being inderclocked but there isn't a performance difference

Comment: @Ramhound but can the memory speed be increased to 1600MHz from BIOS? Will the CPU support it?

Comment: You provided zero information about your motherboard (except it supports the faster memory you want to purchase) or CPU.  It's literally not possible for me to say if your CPU will support the faster memory.

Comment: @Ramhound, I have added more details to the question.

Comment: You will not be able to overclock your memory with the hardware you have.  The reason your system is underclocking the memory is because its unable to overclock the memory frequency.  As I pointed out, you will recieve virtually zero performance gain between 1333Mhz and 1600Mhz memory anyways.

Answer (score 1):

It could run at 1600 MHz but for whatever reason your system is using 1333 MHz. This usually can be changed in the BIOS (if possible). [Your CPU](https://ark.intel.com/products/76751/Intel-Pentium-Processor-N3510-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz) doesn't seem support anything other than 1333 MHz. Faster modules are clocked down.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I get correctly, you mean even if I get a 1600 MHz module, it'll be clocked down to 1333 MHz; meaning the system will still run at 1333 MHz right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Seth says, it will be clocked down.
However, you could benefit from adding maximum amount of RAM. Your motherboard supports up to 16GB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

If you put RAM with a higher frequency but your Computer does not support the higher frequency the RAM will run at a lower speed. The answers before this one suggested the same.